# Call event associated with a method parameter

Tags: c#

A method has an input parameter that is a forms control object (say a ComboBox).  I want to determine if the control has a particular event registered and, if so, trigger the event.  I tried to enter the following code but the compiler rejects it because the selected event (in the example SelectedIndexChanged) can only appear to the left of the += or -= operators.

```
private void DoSearch(ComboBox cb) {

     // Once the search is complete, I want to call the event

     // Does this control have a SelectedIndexChanged event registered?
     if (cb.SelectedIndexChanged != null) {
        // call the event
        cb.SelectedIndexChanged(cb, EventArgs.Empty);
     }
}
```

Comment: Where is your actual _question_? There is not enough detail in your post to understand even how the "search routine the caller desired" is specified, nor how an event handler is "registered" for a control. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates the question, along with a precise explanation of what you've tried in that code, what happened, and how that was different from what you want.

Comment: The code I provided does not work.  The compiler rejects it because SelectedIndexChanged event can only appear to the left of a += or -+

Comment: Then you should say so in your post. It's still not clear what your actual _question_ is, but if I am understanding correctly, your post is a duplicate of [Raise an event of a class from a different class in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4378339). If you agree, please close this question as a duplicate of that one. If you don't agree, please edit your question so that it describes clearly how it's different from the other question, providing [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a precise explanation of why that code doesn't do what you want.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: I wasn't looking to raise the event, just call the method if it existed.  Setting the 'SelectedIndex' will solve the issue though.  Thanks.

Comment: @MarvinThompson - I think you have a terminology issue. You "raise" events, you can't "call" them. There is no "method" to "call".

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you're asking. Only the class in which the event is defined can raise the event.

Not even subclasses can call a parent class's events. You might see, in a subclass, methods called `On*` (i.e. `OnSelectedIndexChanged`). These are used to allow the subclass to call into the base class where the event is defined to raise the event. These methods are usually marked as `protected` so that only child classes can call them.

Otherwise, the way to get `SelectedIndexChanged` to be raised is to set the `SelectedIndex` property.