# javascript equivalent change() in c#

Tags: c#

I would like to trigger the onchange with c# because i can't use js

```
        (Master.FindControl("ComboBox") as CustomComboBox).SelectedValue = foo;
        (Master.FindControl("ComboBox") as CustomComboBox).change();
```

the ".change()" won't work. Is there a way in c# to make it work ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `change` is an event, you can't use standard method call to trigger other events in C# like JS does. You need to use `protected void ComboBox_Change(object sender, EventArgs e)` event handler in case of ASP.NET webforms code-behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, [there is no generic way to trigger another object's events in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4378339/87698).

However, there is a simple workaround: Extract the code you execute in your ComboBox's onchange event into a separate method and call this method.